# Power BI DAX, Median Function not working

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to get a table with medians per business line in power BI using the following:

```
Med = GROUPBY(Sales,Sales[Business Line],"Medians",MEDIANX(CURRENTGROUP(),Sales[Sales in USD]))
```

I get an error even though AVERAGEX, SUMX are working perfectly

Anyone ? :)

Thank you very much,
Jeremy

Comment: What is the error your getting?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this for a bit and found that this GROUPBY/MEDIANX pattern seems to be a bug.

Try the following workaround:

```
Med = 

SUMMARIZE(
    Sales,
    Sales[Business Line],
    "Medians",
    MEDIANX(Sales,Sales[Sales in USD])
)
```

For this expression, it is also important that Sales[Sales in USD] isn't data type "Whole Number" (given the name, I wouldn't think that's an issue) as that will create an error in MedianX

Hope it helps.